# Animate the height of inputAccessoryView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, inputaccessoryview

Hello I' trying to change the height of a button set as inputAccessoryView once I click on it.

Unfortunately it seems only to change the position but not the height.

Can Anyone help me out? Below my code.

Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



 @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    var SendButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        SendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.width, 30)
        SendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 184/255.0, green: 56/255.0, blue: 56/255.0, alpha: 1)
        SendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
        SendButton.addTarget(self, action: "sendNotification", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func sendNotification(){

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.SendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, -340, UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.width, 30)
            self.SendButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 300/255.0, green: 56/255.0, blue: 56/255.0, alpha: 1)
            self.SendButton.setTitle("Hello", forState: .Normal)

        })
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.inputAccessoryView = self.SendButton
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your animation block you are changing the y posistion of the frame in CGRectMake rather than the height. that's why the position is changing and not the height.

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
 // Your problem is the line below
        self.SendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, -340, UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.width, 30) 
    })
```

The function parameters of the function CGRectMake are 
 `CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height)`

Change the code below to your desired height.

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        self.SendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.width, yourDesiredHeight) 
    })
```

But this doesn't help in changing the height of the input accessory once it was set.

First add a separate `UIView` as input accessory(with added height) and add the button into this `UIView`. Animate the button inside after that. This works.
You can check out the code in the gist 
https://gist.github.com/rakeshbs/539827925df923e41afe

Comment: Hello,thanks for the reply. But unfortunately even changing the height it doesn't work. The height still remain the same. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: I have solved the problem by using another view with added height as the inputaccessoryview and adding the button into it. check the code. https://gist.github.com/rakeshbs/539827925df923e41afe