# How to animate inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to animate the inputAccessoryView - for context the use-case is once fields are validated the button should appear.

I initially tried setting the center point for the button to be below the keyboard and then animating it, but that didn't work. I also tried changing the frame, no luck either.

I then found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818374/animate-the-height-of-inputaccessoryview-swift) seeming to describe what I wanted to achieve, opting to use a UIView and adding the button as a subview. However that doesn't seem to work either; in fact *any* changes to the view/button after it has appeared aren't reflected.

I read the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) on input views and it doesn't explicitly state you're unable to make changes to the view once it's initialized, so I'm unsure if I'm just doing something wrong or this is undocumented.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
  get {
    let height:CGFloat = 50
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    view.addSubview(inputButton)
    return view
  }
}

var inputButton: UIButton {
    let height:CGFloat = 50
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, height, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 0))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    button.setTitle("Submit", forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "didPressButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), 50)
    return button
}

// Called on text field change
@IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
  inputButton.setTitle("Testing Change!", forState: .Normal)
  textField.reloadInputViews()
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
    delay: 0,
    options: .CurveEaseOut,
    animations: {
      self.inputButton.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), -50)
      // self.inputButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), -50)
      self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

You'll notice I tried both setting the title and actually animating. I also used `setNeedsLayout`, and even found reference in the Apple docs to a method named `reloadInputViews` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/reloadInputViews)) that is supposed to refresh the custom input view when called on the first responder. But none of this works.

I've seen this in-action in the Thumbtack app. So either there's a way to get this to work or they aren't using inputAccessoryViews, which would seem terribly hacky.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue. I changed the property `inputButton` into a regular variable and defined it's attributed in `viewDidLoad` as opposed to a computed property. I also removed the override of `inputAccessoryView` and instead made a `backgroundView` UIView that I then assigned manually as the inputAccessoryView for the textField. Here's the code:

```
var inputButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
var inputBackgroundView: UIView!
let inputButtonHeight:CGFloat = 50

override func viewDidLoad() {
  inputButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, inputButtonHeight, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), inputButtonHeight)
  inputButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "00BCD4")
  inputButton.titleLabel?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  inputButton.setTitle(inputAccessoryTitle, forState: .Normal)
  inputButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Font.Medium, size: 10)
  inputButton.addTarget(self, action: "didPressButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
  inputButton.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), inputButtonHeight * 2)

  inputBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), 50))
  inputBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  inputBackgroundView.addSubview(inputButton)

  textField.inputAccessoryView = inputBackgroundView
}
```

And then just animated the center of the button on validation.

I suppose this is some issue with computed properties I'm unaware of, they're technically functions that re-calculate on each call, though I didn't think that would be an issue.